# Modify Torrent file when clients are using it, possible?

Tags: c#, java, bittorrent, magnet-uri

I trying to build an application that is using the torrent technology to make it easier to share the files between friends.

The question are, is it possible to modify a torrent at runtime and that everyone using the torrent then are possible to fetch the update version of the list of files. Could be that a file is modified, added, deleted etc and the it should be changed in the torrent file. The file distributed among friends is fairly easy, but will any "torrent-lib" be ok with it?

I haven't digged down to the torrent-spec entirely but I have search a lot and can't find any other that have asked this question.

Also would the same work if using magnets instead of torrent files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify a torrent after creation, for that will modify it's hash and therefore create an entirely new torrent.

Answer (score 1):

Ye you can modify a torrent 
I have modified torrent by self with an application named " Maketorrent 2.1 "
But sadly I can't use this application now because it can only run over the computers using Win 98,NT,XP etc. It does not supports Win Vista and 7.

The environment of the program is not visible completely when running on Win 7 but if you have a PC with Win XP you can still use it.